# How to override Dockerfile's entrypoint `/bin/sh` from kubernetes job's deployment yml?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have an entrypoint defines as `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]` in `Dockerfile`. The docker image contains most of the shell scripts. But later on I added a Golan scripts, which I want to run from kubernetes job. But due to entrypoint defined as `/bin/sh`, it gives me error `No such file or directory` when I try to run the compiled and installed go binary through `args` in yml of kubernetes job's deployment descriptor.

Any well defined way to achieve such goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As standing in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes) you can override docker's entrypoint by using `command` section of pod's definition in deployment.yaml, example from docs:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: command-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-command
spec:
  containers:
  - name: command-demo-container
    image: debian
    command: ["printenv"]
    args: ["HOSTNAME", "KUBERNETES_PORT"]
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
```